# pip shows warning when downloading any module

Tags: python, homebrew

I have been out of the loop with python for a while and I was trying to install some modules to get some python tools working. When I ran `pip install -r requirements.txt`, I got the error:

```
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated
 and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew
 Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
```

I am using python from homebrew, and I haven't found any useful information on the GitHub issue on how to get the error to go away.

Any help would be appreciated